# How to arrange elements of a vector based on a square matrix

Tags: r

I have a vector that results from a square matrix as below

```
P = as.vector(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2))
```

What would be the simplest way of arranging this vector to get a response similar to what I have below as columns

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4
```

I have been able to arrange the first 2 columns as

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- expand.grid(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4),2))
df1 <- df %>% arrange_all()
df = expand.grid(a = df1[,1], b = df1[,1])
df[,c(2,1)]
```

The last column should repeat as a whole through

```
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
as.vector(apply(matrix(P, nrow = 2), 2, rep, 4))
 [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4

paste(as.vector(apply(matrix(P, nrow = 2), 2, rep, 4)), collapse = ',')
[1] "1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4"
```

Comment: I edited the question, but this would work for the last row. Is there a way I would do everything together? preferably using `expand.grid()` or something that would avoid using matrix notations